# What is the runtime to compute the ordered higher-order Voronoi diagram?

Tags: voronoi-diagrams

The ordered order-k Voronoi diagram (sometimes written OOKVD) partitions the plane into regions such that the k closest sites are the same and in the same order for all the points in a region.

I am interested in particular in the case k=n, the number of sites.

I would also like to know the upper and lower bounds in the worst-case of the number of faces.

I have found literature saying that these have been studied (e.g., http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6222139/), but I failed to find those results in the references (mostly, they just define the OOKVD, and not discuss their combinatorial and algorithmic complexity).